# String to Mongodb query

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb

I have a string, i want to convert this to mongodb query.

```
MongoClient.connect(global_vars.db.mongo.url,function(err, db) {
   if(err) { throw err;    }
   var dbo=db.db("profilemanager"); 
  var query="dbo.collection('userinfo').find({_id:'66949710005'},{'_id':0,'subscriptions':1})";
  q1.toArray(function(err,result){
    if(err) throw err; 
    console.log(result);
  });

 });
```

It is displaying an error saying that toArray is not a function. I want to do that in above procedure because i have to read this query from excel sheet and then process it. please let me know how to address this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use the **eval()** function to convert the string to js expression or code :

> ```
> var query=eval("dbo.collection('userinfo').find({_id:'66949710005'},{'_id':0,'subscriptions':1})");
> ```